# Split a pandas dataframe column with inconsistant data

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column 'suffix' which I want to split in to columns 'suffix' and 'letter'
However the data is bit dirty:

```
'suffix'
 7
 D-25
 K110
 NO7
 NO-8
```

The result I'm aiming for:

```
'suffix'   'character'
     7        Nan
     25       D
     110      K
     7        NO
     8        NO
```

It's going to be difficult to do this with pandas Series.str.split?
I've looked into regular expressions but I have no experience with those and I couldn't find an example I can work with.

Comment: you don't seem to need complex solution - in python you can parse string and check with str.isdigit() method and put digit in suffix and rest in character; at least it works with your example data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by passing Pandas a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?P<char>[A-Z]*)-*(?P<suf>\d+)')

>>> s = pd.Series(['7', 'D-25', 'K110', 'NO7', 'NO8'])

>>> s.str.extract(regex).replace('', 'NaN')
  char  suf
0  NaN    7
1    D   25
2    K  110
3   NO    7
4   NO    8
```

Answer (score 2):

I started writing this before @Brad Solomon's answer. His is shorter, but this approach shows some built-in regex processing within Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    "7",
    "D-25",
    "K110",
    "NO7",
    "NO-8"
], columns=["original",])
df["suffix"] = df["original"].str.extract("(\D+)").str.replace("-","")
df["character"] = df["original"].str.extract("(\d+)")
```

This gives you a DataFrame like this:

```
  original suffix character
0        7    NaN         7
1     D-25     D-        25
2     K110      K       110
3      NO7     NO         7
4     NO-8    NO-         8
```